# How can we run gcloud/gsutil/bq command for different accounts in parallel in one server?

Tags: gcloud

I have installed gcloud/bq/gsutil command line tool in one linux server.
And we have several accounts configured in this server.

```css
**gcloud config configurations list**
NAME  IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT     PROJECT DEFAULT_ZONE  DEFAULT_REGION
gaa   True       a@xxx.com    a
gab  False       b@xxx.com    b
```

Now I have problem to both run gaa/gab in this server at same time. Because they have different access control on BigQuery and Cloud Stroage.
I will use below commands (bq and gsutil commands):

1. Set up account

   `Gcloud config set account a@xxx.com`
2. Copy data from bigquery to Cloud

   `bq extract --compression=GZIP --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 'nl:82421.ga_sessions_20161219' gs://ga-data-export/82421/82421_ga_sessions_20161219_*.json.gz`
3. Download data from Cloud to local system

   `gsutil -m cp gs://ga-data-export/82421/82421_ga_sessions_20161219*gz`

If only run one account, it is not a problem.
But there are several accounts need to run on one server at same time, I have no idea how to deal with this case.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`gcloud` documentation on configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations), you can switch your active configuration via the `--configuration` flag for any `gcloud` command. However, `gsutil` does not have such a flag; you must set the environment variable `CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME`:

```
$ # Shell 1
$ export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=gaa
$ gcloud # ...
$ # Shell 2
$ export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=gab
$ gsutil # ...
```